# How to remove unwanted text surrounding a Regex search in PANDAS?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I had a CSV that had rows that looked like:

```
EXT_TRANS_ID=689129825 - Joe Smith
```

which I needed to extract the code out of and move to a new column. To do this I created a new empty column in the CSV (the CSV is called testReport) and set an index on the column with the ID that needs to be extracted (this column is called Ancillary) and the column where the ID needs to be moved to (this column is called SlateID).

I set the indexes like this:

```
index_ancillary = testReport.columns.get_loc('Ancillary')
index_slateID = testReport.columns.get_loc('Slate ID')
```

and used this ID pattern:

```
id_pattern = r'(\b\d{9})$'
```

in order to write this for loop:

```
for row in range(0, len(testReport)):
    slateID = re.search(id_pattern, str(testReport.iat[row, index_ancillary]))
    testReport.iat[row, index_slateID] = slateID
```

which identified the pattern within the Ancillary column and moved it to the slateID column. This successfully moves the ID into the SlateID column, but the result looks like this for each row in the new column (for about 300 rows):

```
<re.Match object; span=(12, 23), match='=123456789 '> 
<re.Match object; span=(12, 23), match='=987654321 '>
<re.Match object; span=(12, 23), match='=999955559 '>
```

Is there any way to remove the text surrounding the nine letter ID from the left and right, so the column could just look like this:

```
123456789
987654321
999955559
```

One possible solution I saw in a video was to add the .group() method to the end of my for loop like this:

```
for row in range(0, len(testReport)):
    slateID = re.search(id_pattern, str(testReport.iat[row, index_ancillary]).group())
    testReport.iat[row, index_slateID] = slateID
```

However, when I do this I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'
```

One possible solution if all this text cannot be removed is to just remove the stuff to the right of the code, which should be sufficient for what I need to use the SlateID column for in the future.

Sorry in advance if something is unclear, I can edit/add any clarification necessary.

EDIT:

Using the new ID Pattern suggested by the solution, I added this to the code:

```
for row in range(0, len(testReport)):
        try:
            slateID = re.search( id_pattern, str(testReport.iat[row, index_ancillary])).group()
            testReport.iat[row, index_slateID] = slateID
        except AttributeError:
            slateID = re.search( id_pattern, str(testReport.iat[row, index_ancillary]))
            testReport.iat[row, index_slateID] = slateID
```

which catches the AttributeError and removes the .group() method.

Comment: I don't think you should be looping for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

`slateID = re.search( id_pattern, str(testReport.iat[row, index_ancillary]).group() )`

to

`slateID = re.search( id_pattern, str(testReport.iat[row, index_ancillary]) ).group()`

you are using `.group()` with arg string instead of calling it on `re.search`

matching to `id_pattern = r'(\b\d{9})$'` returning NoneType because $ matches end of string, use  `id_pattern = r"(\b\d{9})"`

```
>>> re.search(r"(\b\d{9})", "EXT_TRANS_ID =689129825  - Joe Smith").group()
'689129825'
```

Comment: This gives me the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: probably your regex pattern is not matching. `re.search(r"(\b\d{9})$", "EXT_TRANS_ID=689129825").group()` is giving `'689129825'` which seems to be working

Comment: however, `re.search(r"(\b\d{9})$", "EXT_TRANS_ID=689129825 - Joe Smith"` is not matching

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: hm, after changing the ID pattern I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I fixed it! I put the for loop in a try-except loop that caught the AttributeError for None values. Thank you so much.